# Laravel - function where() after the model has already been retrieved

Tags: php, laravel

Can I use the function where() or some equivalent after the model has already been retrieved?
For example:

```
    $head = Equipment::where('user_id', $fighter->id)->where('lvl_after_reduction', '<=', $fighter->attributes->lvl)->where('durability', '>', 0)
                      ->whereHas('item', function ($q) {
                          $q->where('type_id', 1);
                      })->where('wear', 1)->first();

    $torso = Equipment::where('user_id', $fighter->id)->where('lvl_after_reduction', '<=', $fighter->attributes->lvl)->where('durability', '>', 0)->whereHas('item', function ($q) {
        $q->where('type_id', 2);
    })->where('wear', 1)->first();

    if ($torso == null)
        $torso = Equipment::where('user_id', $fighter->id)->where('lvl_after_reduction', '<=', $fighter->attributes->lvl)->where('durability', '>', 0)->whereHas('item', function ($q) {
            $q->where('type_id', 3);
        })->where('wear', 1)->first();

    $hands = Equipment::where('user_id', $fighter->id)->where('lvl_after_reduction', '<=', $fighter->attributes->lvl)->where('durability', '>', 0)->whereHas('item', function ($q) {
        $q->where('type_id', 4);
    })->where('wear', 1)->first();

    $waist = Equipment::where('user_id', $fighter->id)->where('lvl_after_reduction', '<=', $fighter->attributes->lvl)->where('durability', '>', 0)->whereHas('item', function ($q) {
        $q->where('type_id', 5);
    })->where('wear', 1)->first();

    $feet = Equipment::where('user_id', $fighter->id)->where('lvl_after_reduction', '<=', $fighter->attributes->lvl)->where('durability', '>', 0)->whereHas('item', function ($q) {
        $q->where('type_id', 6);
    })->where('wear', 1)->first();

    $amulet = Equipment::where('user_id', $fighter->id)->where('lvl_after_reduction', '<=', $fighter->attributes->lvl)->where('durability', '>', 0)->whereHas('item', function ($q) {
        $q->where('type_id', 8);
    })->where('wear', 1)->first();

    $first_ring = Equipment::where('user_id', $fighter->id)->where('lvl_after_reduction', '<=', $fighter->attributes->lvl)->where('durability', '>', 0)->whereHas('item', function ($q) {
        $q->where('type_id', 9);
    })->where('wear', 1)->first();

    $secound_ring = Equipment::where('user_id', $fighter->id)->where('lvl_after_reduction', '<=', $fighter->attributes->lvl)->where('durability', '>', 0)->whereHas('item', function ($q) {
        $q->where('type_id', 9);
    })->where('wear', 2)->first();

    $right_hand = Equipment::where('user_id', $fighter->id)->where('lvl_after_reduction', '<=', $fighter->attributes->lvl)->where('durability', '>', 0)->whereHas('item', function ($q) {
        $q->whereIn('type_id', [10, 11]);
    })->where('wear', 1)->first();
```

Can I combine these queries into one? Because I have a lot of queries to database per page.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Please combine your where clause in one function like this

```
$torso = Equipment::where([['user_id', $fighter->id], ['wear', 1]])->first();
```

It is much cleaner.

Yes it is possible to use `where` function after running a query as long as it returns collection.

eg 
You can do

```
Equipment::all();
```

Then apply `where` clause to the collection it returns.
Query like this return an `eloquent collection`.
Go to this documentation page https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-collections to see all the functions available for eloquent collection.

However using `where` clause to return value of query that end with `first()` is not possible as it does not return a collection.